# Java RPG Dynamic skills and design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on a RPG-game for my studies, we need to use design patterns and I am trying to code dynamic character skills. For example, I there would be items that, when equipped,  add new skills that the character did not have before (heal...).

For that, I wanted to use the decorator pattern, but with this one, we can not add methods or attributes to a class, just modify those already existing, right?

So is there a dynamic way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of patterns out there; did your teacher ask for a specific pattern or group of patterns? Also, patterns are things that make sense some times. Use them only when they help  solve a problem, not because they are cool.

In this case, decorators *can* be used. As you write, they are not supposed to add external methods or attributes. So you would need `getHealingPower()`, `getArmorValue()` and so on for even naked characters; and each wrapped decorator would modify returned values for things it cared about: a `HealingBookDecorator` would return `wrappedObject.getHealingPower() + 15`. However, **I find them quite ugly for this scenario**, because the character would have no way of removing the healing book to leave it on the floor, or to pick up a better book. Decorated objects are generally unaware of their decorators. Plus, if your character is named `bob`, it would be weird to dress him using `StripedShirtDecorator(RedScarfDecorator(PolkaDotTrousersDecorator(bob)))`.

If I had to implement this, each `Item` would have a `String description` and contain a `Map<Stat, Integer> modifiers` (where `Stat` is an `enum` of valid statistics, such as healing, armor value, maximum HP, and so on). A `Character` would have an `ArrayList<Item> inventory`, a `Map<Stat, Integer> baseStats` his or her base stats, and another `Map<Stat, Integer> currentStats` which would contain the result of merging `baseStats` and the `modifiers` of each `Item` in the characters' inventory, and which would need updating every time the character levelled up or added or removed something from his inventory.

To check the level of `Stat.MusicProficiency` in a `Character` called `lisaSimpson`, you would then write `lisaSimpson.getStat(Stat.MusicProficiency);`. This has the advantage that it would be very easy to add new types of items (they would be object instances, not classes), and inventory management would be considerably simplified.

Comment: However, you *could* use decorators when drawing the character - one could draw clothes, another would add on the armor, and another could paint an HP bar on top. This would be fine, because the character never needs to know how he is being painted...

Comment: Whoa, this is encouraging. I'm pretty new to game development (just started a couple of weeks ago), and this is *exactly* the way I'm doing it—except I'm using an std::unordered_map<std::string, int> instead of an enum. Awesome!

Comment: @AmagicalFishy convergent evolution :-). However, I recommend against plain strings, because spelling errors can cause a lot of grief ("Armor" vs "Armour"), and with enums, you get compile-time warnings and auto-complete.